# Simple (recursion) variadic template "accumulate_for" function with compile problems

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I want to write a variadic template or const expressions which 1) execute a template functor `N` times and 2) accumulates the result. I wrote a small example which actually fails compilation as soon as I move the function which gets executed into a template functor. I have the feel I am close to the solution, but maybe I am wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct F {
    template <int id>
    static int run(int val) {
        return id * val;
    }
};

template<unsigned int n>
struct accumulate_for
{
    template <class Funct>
    static int get(int val) {
        return 
        (
        accumulate_for<n-1>::get(val) 
        + 
        Funct::run<n>(val)
        );
    }
};

template<>
struct accumulate_for<0>
{
    template <class Funct>
    static int get(int val) {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << accumulate_for<3>::get<F>(1) << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: [alternative with std::index_sequence](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9946dfd1a8890ef)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `accumulate_for<n>::get` is a member function template, so you have to specify template argument when calling it.
2. You need to use [template keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) to indicate that `get` and `run` (which are both dependent names) are templates.

e.g.

```
template<unsigned int n>
struct accumulate_for
{
    template <class Funct>
    static int get(int val) {
        return 
        (
        accumulate_for<n-1>::template get<Funct>(val) 
        //                   ~~~~~~~~    ~~~~~~~
        + 
        Funct::template run<n>(val)
        //     ~~~~~~~~
        );
    }
};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/XMFAP21126)

For more info about the usage of the `template` keyword, refer to [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3309790)

Comment: I dont get why template keyword is necessary. The compiler should see this?!

Comment: @dgrat Have you checked the link? In short, without that, for `get<Funct>`, the compiler won't regard `get` as a template name, then `<` will be parsed as the less-than sign. On the other hand, there might be some specifictions of `accumulate_for` (e.g. `accumulate_for<99>` ?), which has a static data member named `get` then make `accumulate_for<n-1>::get < something` valid.